# Continuous Delivery in SOA

Tags: soa, continuous-deployment

How does Continuous Delivery feed into a SOA architecture?

As each SOA service should be independent does that mean we need a individual pipeline for each service? How does that affect when there are 100's of services?

We could group services into deployable units to group services.

The biggest issue I see is in the testing in the 100's of different version configuration setups.

Is there a model to base this on?

Comment: It really depends I guess. IN one organization they had different testing methodologies depending on where in the SOA catalog these services sat. For example technical services i.e. send mail service was tested independently and Account level service and SAP level services were mostly tested as a group to lessen the load. This all depends on your SOA governance policies. Without those in place... it gets messy quick.

Answer (score 0):

1. In case you have a microservices architecture where services are loosely coupled , you should ideally  have integration tests that can "black-box" test one individual service that has changed . In such a case, you can easily build a separate pipeline for each service. You really don't want to deploy 100 different components every time you change 1 or 2 components
2. By a separate pipeline, i am not referring to a separate deploy codebase for each of the services. You can generalize your containers and services so that the deploy code can be automated.
3. Coming to configurations, you should separate out SOA using a restful framework. In that case you do not have tight coupling between components and a 
   range f smoke tests can easily determine if a prod deploy of a particular service is succesful or not

Comment: I don't see how having 100 separate pipelines is manageable. Especially where there is a dependency between services, such as Orchestration services.

Comment: We have 40 different services , and our deployment is dynamic to handle individual service deploys. The trick is to have a generic deployment code  so that you just need to pass in a service name as a parameter and the rest of the flow is automated for you. You can even use container (eg docker) based deploys  to achieve this

Comment: In terms of Continuous Delivery there may be several changes on different services when I want to push a release.

Say we have
#1 - Service A updated
#2 - Service B updated
#3 - Service C updated

I want to at the click of a button, release all changes from the previous release. For instance if the previous release is #1, and #2 and #3 are available. I want to click "build #3" which will include #2 and #3 (all changes since the last release)

I don't see how this is "do-able" with different pipelines.